# My boolean of an object gets changed without the program doing anything

Tags: java, boolean

I've been debugging for hours, and I finally found where the problem is. NOW I have to fix it :)

I thinks something strange happens.

I'm creating an date app, where I calculate which day it is (with leapyear corrections etc).

I have a method, where I take a Year object.

```
private int totalDays(Year yearnumber) {
    System.out.println("Boolean check 1: " + yearnumber.getLeapYear()); 

    //calculate days for whole year//
    int daysWholeYear = 0; 
    for (int i = year.getYearZero(); i < yearnumber.getYear(); i++) {
        // here i will add all the days (366) from the leapyears //
        if (yearnumber.isLeapYear(i) == true) {
            totalDays += year.getLengthyear() + 1; 
            System.out.println("Boolean check 2: " + yearnumber.getLeapYear()); 
        } else {
            totalDays += year.getLengthyear();  
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Boolean check 3: " + yearnumber.getLeapYear());
```

My first two boolean checks are ok.

Code (without the boolean check looped in the for loop)

```
Boolean check 1: true
Boolean check 2: true
Boolean check 3: false
```

I need my Boolean in the next lines of my method, where I calculate the days of the months (non whole years). However, my program now thinks that the year is not a leap year and therefore makes wrong calculations.

Because this Boolean changes in my program, the rest of my calculation are off. Can someone explain my why this happens? :)

EDIT: code from my year class:

```
public class Year {
    private static int yearzero = 1753; 
    private static int lengthYear = 365; 
    private int year; 
    private boolean leapYear; 
    private int startYear; //are used for an interval calculations
    private int eindYear; // 


    public Year(int year) {
        this.year = year; 
        this.leapYear = isLeapYear(year);
    }

    boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return leapYear = (year % 400 == 0) || 
        ((year % 100) != 0 && (year % 4 == 0));
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;  
    }

    public int getYearzero () {
        return yearZero; 
    }

    public int getLengthYear() {
        return lengthYear; 
    }

    public boolean getLeapYear() {
        return leapYear; 
   }
```

}

Comment: Can you share the code of your `Year` class?

Comment: Is it `Jaar` class or `Year` class?

Comment: I've translated it, must have missed it. Will edit it.

Comment: This is not a debugging service

Comment: @Bohemian I don't understand why you say that. I'm trying to understand why my Boolean changes. I'm a student and I'm trying to understand Java :) I'm sorry if I came over the wrong way.

Comment: Don't code-dump into the question. Isolate the few lines that matter and post those *only*. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Bohemian, thanks for sharing, I'm still pretty new to this site :) But to the be honest I shared the extra year code after the request in the chatbox :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `isLeapYear` function sets the object's `leapYear` variable. This is because the `yearnumber.isLeapYear(i) == true` will fail, and `yearnumber.leapYear` will be set to `false`.

Change

```
 boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return leapYear = (year % 400 == 0) || 
        ((year % 100) != 0 && (year % 4 == 0));
    }
```

to:

```
 boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return ((year % 400 == 0) || 
        ((year % 100) != 0 && (year % 4 == 0)));
    }
```

Comment: Wow, such a small change, and it changes my whole program! Programming ia awesome! Thank you for your reply, it makes a lot of sense to me now!